# Quarto book publish produces "LaTeX Error: File `scrreprt.cls' not found"

Tags: latex, rstudio, bookdown, quarto

When I attempt to re-publish a Quarto Book to an established url on Quarto Pub, I receive an error in the terminal. The error message in the terminal upon which it stops before republishing is:

```
"compilation failed- no matching packages
LaTeX Error: File `scrreprt.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name:
Emergency stop.
<read *>

l.10 ^^M
```

I am unclear on how to interpret the error message.

I recently transitioned this document from bookdown to a Quarto Book. In the past I have successfully published the content to a Quarto Pub url using the following terminal command:

```
quarto publish quarto-pub
```

The full index.log file is available on the project GitHub repository at https://github.com/Kenai-Watershed-Forum/kenai_thermal_imagery_v2/blob/main/index.log

The main repository is located at https://github.com/Kenai-Watershed-Forum/kenai_thermal_imagery_v2.

I have verified the most current versions of R, RStudio, and TeXWorks are installed.

```
> version
               _                                
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32               
arch           x86_64                           
os             mingw32                          
crt            ucrt                             
system         x86_64, mingw32                  
status                                          
major          4                                
minor          2.2                              
year           2022                             
month          10                               
day            31                               
svn rev        83211                            
language       R                                
version.string R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
nickname       Innocent and Trusting
```

Comment: try to reinstall `tinytex`.

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstalled the current version of tinytex, and restarted the PC with the same result.

Comment: I also reproduce the same error when attempting to publish an unaltered Quarto Book template, on two separate PCs.

Answer (score 0):

In the R Console, type `tinytex::uninstall_tinytex()` and run.
Then, in the R Terminal, type `quarto install tinytex` and run.

Comment: OP stated in the comments that they tried uninstalling and reinstalling and it did not resolved the issue. Please check all parts of a question, including the comments, before posting. Thanks